# BitBucket Server -- running multiple server proxies?

Tags: ssl, proxy, reverse-proxy, bitbucket

I've got BitBucket server 5.11

I'd like to run multiple proxies in front of it, with different hostnames. So that `bitbucket.corp.com` as well as `corp.bitbucket.com` can be hosted on seperate proxies.  We terminate SSL at the proxy.

You can set up a single proxy, no problem, [based on the docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver0511/administering-bitbucket-server/proxying-and-securing-bitbucket-server) -- which we have done

However, I'd like to know if anyone has tried using multiple `server.proxy` settings in the `bitbucket.properties` [config file](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/bitbucket-server-config-properties-776640155.html)?

Thanks,

Dan